# Mobclix fails with code -1006

Tags: android, mobclix

I am having problems with Mobclix demo. I have changed my ip and ran the demo but no ads are showing. On my profile I have enabled all ads networks and they are enabled few days ago but no ads are showing except when I set the profile to be on test mode - then I see the test banner.
When I hit the "Refresh Ads" button on their android demo app I see these:

> 09-14 08:54:43.383: V/MobclixAdvertisingView(4521): The ad request failed with error code: -999999
>   09-14 08:54:44.044: V/MobclixAdvertisingView(4521): The ad request returned open allocation code: -111111
>   09-14 08:54:44.044: V/MobclixAdvertisingView(4521): The ad request returned open allocation code: -1006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working now maybe the ads feed was not ready on the server side.